# How to convert @OFFSET function from SPSS to HANA?

Tags: spss, hana

I have to implement some logic from SPSS to HANA. It was ok until I found this function on SPSS: [@OFFSET](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/clem_function_ref_sequence.htm). What is the similar way to implement this function on HANA? I found on SPSS something like:

```
@OFFSET (<Column1>, 1) = column1 and @OFFSET(<Column2>, 1) = Column2
```

[image]

Comment: That would depend on the representation of the records in your code - of which you should include a MWE...

Comment: I wanto to implement the @OFFSET function using SQLScript for HANA. Is that possible?

Comment: Repeating the same question without supplying the additional information requested is not going to help.

Comment: I found some Inspiration from this answer:
[Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089999/628213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using window function LAG()